# How to fill the ListView from another class?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

My problem is follow (I know that selected structure of my classes looks like bizarre, but ...).

1. I have the MainActivity with inner class, that extends AsyncTask to parse HTML from internet.
2. This activity parses HTML-page and fills the ListView in AnotherActivity.
3. AnotherActivity must call the inner AsyncTask and PostExecute must fill the ListView by another data (the sense of this actions that AnotherActivity is results of search and another search means the going to new page of search's results of YouTube)
4. I wrote the next code in PostExecute of AsyncTask:
   where I get Activity with ListView, create adapter and assign it to ListView.

   `ResultsQueryActivity resultsActivity = new ResultsQueryActivity();

       ResourceDataAdapter resourceDataAdapter = new ResourceDataAdapter(resultsActivity,MainActivity.listVideosData);
       resultsActivity.setListAdapter(resourceDataAdapter);`

After execution of this I get the message

```
*02-01 07:40:56.784: E/AndroidRuntime(525): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()*
```

I really have no idea how to resolve it. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have two activities, when both of them seem need to be done on the same activity?

Just use one activity. When parsing is done, update the ListView with your data, then show the ListView. Initially the ListView would be hidden. Your other views (if any) would be hidden as well.

*Or use a ListActivity, doesn't really make a difference.*

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it has something to do with the way you are creating `ResultsQueryActivity`... Typically you would start it via an `Intent` and pass all your video data to it by putting it into a `Bundle`. Try replacing your code in `postExecute()` with something like this (assuming your video data is a `String` array):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultsQueryActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("videodata", MainActivity.listVideosData);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the `ResultsQueryActivity` class, you can retrieve the data in the `onCreate(Bundle b)` method:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String[] videodata = extras.getStringArray("videodata");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate a activity, activities is managed by system.

The flow of the two activity is not very well.

1. If MainActivity is only used to parse html, then it should not exist. Put the the asynctask in AnotherActivity and fill the list in postExecute.
2. If MainActivity must exist, then you should not fill data in the task. Try to parse the data to AnotherActivity, and let it fill data by itself.